# Fehlendes Subjekt in "als am Abend geplündert wurde"

Tags: passive, subject

In dieser Frage geht es um den folgenden Satz aus *[Der Augsburger Kreidekreis](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=NC08CgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT90&ots=awHBrxOiTv&dq=So%20war%20er%20noch%20in%20der%20Stadt%2C%20als%20die%20kaiserlichen%20Truppen%20sie%20st%C3%BCrmten%2C%20und%20als%20am%20Abend%20gepl%C3%BCndert%20wurde%2C%20versteckte%20er%20sich%20in%20einer%20Grube%20im%20Hof%2C%20wo%20die%20Farben%20aufbewahrt%20wurden&pg=PT90#v=onepage&q&f=false)* von Bertolt Brecht, einer Geschichte, die zu der Zeit des Dreißigjährigen Krieges geschieht.  »Er« ist ein Schweizer Protestant, der eine Gerberei besitzt.

> So war er noch in der Stadt, als die kaiserlichen Truppen sie stürmten, und **als am Abend geplündert wurde**, versteckte er sich in einer Grube im Hof, wo die Farben aufbewahrt wurden.

#### Fragen

- Was ist das Subjekt des hervorgehobenen *als*-Satzes?
- Soll ein *sie* (für *Stadt)* zwischen *als* und *am Abend* stehen?
- Wenn man das Subjekt des Satzes auslassen kann, warum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hier wird das *unpersönliche Passiv* in einem *subjektlosen Passivsatz* verwendet (eine Suche nach den kursiv gesetzten Begriffen ergibt reichlich weitere Informationen). Je nach Satzstellung wird gegebenenfalls an erster Stelle im Satz das Pronomen *es* anstelle eines Subjekts verwendet:

> Es wurde am Abend geplündert.
>
> Am Abend wurde geplündert.
>
> Die Polizei rückte aus, da geplündert worden war.
>
> Es war geplündert worden, also rückte die Polizei aus.

Comment: Ein anderes schönes Beispiel für einen Satz ohne Subjekt: "Nach drei Stück Sahnetorte wurde ihr schlecht." :-)

Comment: Viel schöner, kein Zweifel. Unterscheidet sich vom Originalsatz dadurch, dass hier eine Aktivkonstruktion gar nicht möglich ist – es sei denn, man vertraut [dem Internet](http://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/einem_schlecht_werden.htm).

Comment: Geplündert worden war, also rückte die Polizei aus. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`als am Abend geplündert wurde` ist ein eingeschobener / untergeordneter Nebensatz, der nicht für sich alleine stehen kann. Nebensätze müssen nicht vollständig sein, manchmal fehlt das Subjekt, manchmal das Prädikat.

Man könnte den relevanten Abschnitt des Satzes so umformulieren, dann wird klar, dass es sich eigentlich um einen Satzbestandteil zur zeitlichen Bestimmung und keinen eigenständigen Satz handelt:

> Er versteckte sich in einer Grube als am Abend geplündert wurde

Comment: Danke, aber 'als die kaiserlichen Truppen sie stürmten' ist ein untergeordneter Nebensatz, sondern vollständig (mit Subjekt und Prädikat). Ist 'als am Abend geplündert wurde' eine besondere Art untergeordneter Nebensatz?  | Kann man sagen, 'Ich habe Hunger als nach Hause komme'? (Kein 'ich'.)