# Dativ-Ergänzung in Position 1 im Passsiv?

Tags: verb

Ich lerne zurzeit Passiv. Hier ist ein Satz in meinem Übungsbuch:

> (Ich gebe schon mal den Kollegen Beschied, dass wir später kommen.)
>
> Ihnen wurden doch schon Bescheid gegeben!

Jetzt habe ich folgende Fragen:

1.Warum gibt es in diesem Satz keine Nominativ-Ergänzung?  Wie kann man einen solchen Satz formen?

2.Kann man diesen Satz im Passiv Perfekt formen? Könnten Sie ein Beispiel nennen?

Comment: Ähnliche Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35033/fehlendes-subjekt-in-als-am-abend-gepl%c3%bcndert-wurde/35040#35040

Comment: Die akzeptierte Antwort der o.g. Frage zeigt auch, wie das Perfekt gebildet werden kann.

Comment: Sieht ein bisschen nach Hausaufgabe aus, die wir für dich lösen sollen. Und dein Post enthält 3 Flüchtigkeitsfehler. Ein bisschen Mühe könntest du dir schon geben, wenn du eine gute Antwort erwartest. Wie sehen denn deine Antwortversuche aus?

Comment: Entschuldigung, aber es ist nicht meine Hausaufgabe, und ich bin zurzeit kein Student. Zwar ist es ein Satz von "Deutsch für Besserwisser B1" (ich habe das Buch gekauft, um mein Deutsch zu verbessern) , aber das Buch gibt leider keine Antwort für meine Frage. Ich weiß, dass mein Deutsch schlecht ist, deshalb probiere ich es. Ich habe meine Antwortversuche nicht gegeben, weil es anscheinend falsch schient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Er* gibt den Kollegen Bescheid. (Aktiv)
>
> Den Kollegen wird *von ihm* Bescheid gegeben. (Passiv)

Das Subjekt des Aktivsatzes wird zum Objekt des Passivsatzes. Das Objekt im Passivsatz ist oftmals unwichtig und wird weggelassen (im obigen Beispiel "von ihm"). Im Eingangsbeispiel macht das Subjekt im Passivsatz keinen Sinn, da das Subjekt nicht Bescheid gegeben hat bzw. Bescheid geben wird.

> *Den Kollegen* wurde Bescheid gegeben.
>
> *Ihnen* wurde Bescheid gegeben.

Man kann das auch noch hervorheben durch ein unpersönliches Passiv mit Personalpronomen:

> Es wurde ihnen Bescheid gegeben. (Präteritum Passiv).
>
> Es ist ihnen Bescheid gegeben worden (Perfekt Passiv).

Und ohne Pronomen:

> Ihnen ist schon Bescheid gegeben worden. (Perfekt Passiv)

Comment: Vielen Dank! Ganz klar.